# Acceder a lista de comentarios blog wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, blog

¿Alguien sabe en qué template se encuentra la lista de comentarios del blog de Wordpress?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He logrado encontrar el template donde se pinta el tag `<ol class="commentlist">` pero del `<li>` hijo no veo ni rastro... Necesito sobreescribir ese template o la función que lo pinta para maquetarlo con CSS a mi manera.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No entiendo tu duda. El `li` lo tienes señalado en el recuadro rojo ¿no? Tampoco entiendo qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente ¿? En WP los comentarios, se guardan en la Base de datos.

Comment: quiere saber en qué archivo o función de wordpress se pinta eso para saber cómo sobreescribirlo y maquetarlo a mi gusto con CSS

Comment: El archivo lo tienes a la derecha, es `style.css`, pero no te recomendaría que modifiques ese archivo directamente, desde WP 4.7 puedes personalizar CSS desde el área de administración. [Mira este post](https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-easily-add-custom-css-to-your-wordpress-site/), la **opción 1**, porque la opción 2 recomienda hacerlo con un plugin, lo que te recomiendo evitar.

Comment: Y, si te vas a meter a modificar CSS en serio, en profundidad, puedes crear tu propio archivo `.css`  y agregarlo allí donde lo necesites mediante el uso de `wp_enqueue_style` o de otro modo. Así tienes control sobre tu código, por ejemplo para fines de copia de seguridad y otros, incluyendo tu archivo personalizado en tu política de backups. Esto es muy importante si en tu hosting no estás abonado a un paquete de backup. Si pasa algo podrías perder todo tu código personalizado, teniendo que volver a re-escribirlo.

Comment: Disculpame, creo que no me estoy explicando bien. Ya tengo mi propio childtheme creado con su CSS correspondiente.
Además, al poner woocommerce me he visto obligado a sobreescribir templates y funciones en el functions.php de mi childtheme, a veces utilizando hooks, otras reescribiendo el html.

Comment: Ahora lo que necesito es reescribir ese html. 
Quiero poner el comentario del autor y la fecha en la misma línea con un display flex. Y para hacerlo debo meterlo en un solo div.

Comment: Eso puedes hacerlo modificando el CSS usando las clases por defecto desde un CSS personalizado, como ya te he comentado, o rediseñando el código en sí mismo mediante la funcion [`wp_list_comments()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_comments/) de Wordpress. En el enlace, al final, hay varios casos de uso.

Comment: Exacto!! la función `wp_list_comments()` es lo que estaba buscando. Muchísimas gracias de nuevo!!